# How does Realm determine two files are the same RealmObject? (package changes)

Tags: android, package, realm, realm-mobile-platform, realm-migration

What is the criteria Realm uses in android to tell two different files are the same `RealmObject`?
Is it just the class name or the whole package name?

More specifically.

1. Say that I have `com.company.MyRealmObject.kt` and I refactor it to `com.company2.MyRealmObject.kt`.
2. Say that I have `com.company.MyRealmObject.kt` in Gradle module `:app` and I move it to `Say that I have` com.company.MyRealmObject.kt`in Gradle module`:library_db`

Would those action make Realm consider that `MyRealmObject` before and after the change are different `RealmObjects` hence requiring a migration, or would they be considered the same `RealmObjects` regardless of package and file as they have the same simple class name?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

From my experiments, as long as the name of the class is the same, Realm will consider it the same `RealmObject`.
The name of the package of file in the project is not relevant, it's all down to the name of the class.

This seems to be in line with this comment: https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/6403#issuecomment-454427296

> Our proxy classes encode the package path as part of the final class
> name, but moving classes should be fine since the simple name is the
> same, so it should translate to the same simple name in the Realm
> file.